# Removing all but specific string sequence

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list of strings. Each string contains a specific sequence of characters I need - there are three or four exact sequences I'm looking for - and the rest contains unpredictable data that needs to get eliminated from the string. ie:

```
sequences = ['sequenceA', 'sequenceB', 'sequenceC']
bigList = ['Garbage sequenceB blahblah', 'sequenceA nonsense', 'silliness sequenceC', 'total nonsense']
goalList = ['sequenceB', 'sequenceA', 'sequenceC', '']
```

I can use either sub or .replace to remove specific characters, but this is the inversion: I need to remove everything BUT specific strings, and in the case of list elements without an instance of a specific sequence I still need to keep the element so the list stays in order. I'm still new to regex - is there a way to do this I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like a magic one-liner.

```
>>>[ ''.join([x if x in y else '' for x in sequences]) for y in bigList]

['sequenceB', 'sequenceA', 'sequenceC', '']
```

Comment: Oh that is fantastic, and I have no idea why I couldn't spot this as the solution - I walked right up to it, but by then I was overthinking it. Perfect, and thank you.

Comment: At least optimize away rebuilding of the sequence elements, no need to waste CPU cycles on data you already have: `[([x for x in sequences if x in y] or [""])[0] for y in bigList]` ... Still unnecessary slow, but at least a bit more sane.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   goalList = ['' for x in range(len(bigList)]
   for elem in bigList:
       if sequenceA in bigList[elem]:
           goalList[elem] = sequenceA
       if sequenceB in bigList[elem]:
           goalList[elem] = sequenceB
       if sequenceA in bigList[elem]:
           goalList[elem] = sequenceC
```

Of course, adapting it to the things you have on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple double loop:

```
sequences = ['sequenceA', 'sequenceB', 'sequenceC']
bigList = ['Garbage sequenceB blahblah', 'sequenceA nonsense', 'silliness sequenceC', 'total nonsense']

goalList = []
for element in bigList:
    for seq in sequences:
        if seq in element:
            break
    goalList.append(seq if seq in element else "")

print(goalList)
# prints: ['sequenceB', 'sequenceA', 'sequenceC', '']
```

Comment: This is what I was starting to move towards, and I think I was overusing regex - thank you, as a beginner this really helps get my mind around it.

Comment: @ThoureaulyRekt - This is what you should use if you care about performance (and it can be further sped up if needed be, for example if `sequences` is a long list turn it into a set first). Using something just because it looks _neat_ is a road to the hurt-town...